# Code metrics of php - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, metrics, code-metrics

In particular, I am interested to know how many lines of codes there are, but this spans across many files.

I have been using notepad++ to author the code and for each file it does display line numbers but of course I have empty returns to make the code more readable.

Does anyone know of a plugin or tool that I can accurately get the actual lines of code?

Comment: Using PHP Designer or Dreaweaver would be a better alternative....

Comment: You might take a look at this previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300420/good-php-metric-tools though counting the number of lines of code isn't really a significant measure of anything

Comment: @Jens: The OP clearly thought his line count spanned multiple files. The only thing I can imagine he might want to do that is to count the apparant size of a PHP script including the code participating via the transitive closure of a require (aka "include") clause, then it has to be PHP specific. That's sort of a measure of how hard it is to comprehend a script, because requires clauses are typically used to import what amounts to APIs and their implementation.  Harry, please comment?

Answer (score 24):

1. Go to Search -> Find in Files... or use **Ctrl+Shift+F**

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5MKW.png]
2. Find what: **\S+\s*\r\n**

   Filters: ***.php**

   Search Mode **Regular expression**

   Click **Find All**

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRXUX.png]
3. See the 'Find result' in the lower pane

   [image: i.stack.imgur.com/UpuAQ.png]

It's not perfect at all, but it works out of the box. Of course you can also make changes to the regular expression, like only counting lines with:

- White space only: **^\s*\r\n**
- At least one letter or number: **\w+.*\r\n**
- Which are used solely for curly braces: **^(\s*[{}]\s*)+\r\n**
- A class keyword: **class .*\r\n**
- A function keyword: **function .*\r\n**

Comment: [@quamrana](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) thanks for embedding the images.

Answer (score 2):

Google for "php sloc counter". There are plenty of tools to do that, for example:

http://thecodecentral.com/2007/12/26/source-line-of-code-counter

However, this kind of measuring is absolutely useless, so I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Linux:

```
find -name '*.php' | xargs grep -av '\r' | wc -l
```

Windows (PowerShell):

```
(dir -include *.php -recurse | select-string "(?!^$)").count
```

Comment: 1) He mentioned Notepad++ so he's on windows.
2) This would count all lines, not sloc, which is what he wants.

Comment: and empty lines is not in counted now